# Can’t write to btrfs volume (forced readonly)

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs, corruption

Since today, when I try to write moderate amounts of data (MB range) to the btrfs volume on my external hard drive, the volume switches to read-only, interrupting the operation. The volume is very simple (no RAID, no snapshots).

`journalctl` shows the following around the time of the writes:

> ```
> Jan 23 18:34:16 my-machine kernel: BTRFS: device label <...> devid 1 transid 3344 /dev/sdb1
> Jan 23 18:34:16 my-machine kernel: BTRFS info (device sdb1): disk space caching is enabled
> Jan 23 18:34:16 my-machine kernel: BTRFS info (device sdb1): has skinny extents
> Jan 23 18:36:35 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:38:13 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:39:43 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:40:58 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:42:28 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:42:39 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:42:39 my-machine kernel: BTRFS critical (device sdb1): corrupt node: root=7 block=253655810048 slot=106, bad key order, current (18446744073709551606 128 9223372601711906816) next (18446744073709551606 128 564873670656)
> Jan 23 18:42:39 my-machine kernel: BTRFS: error (device sdb1) in btrfs_finish_ordered_io:3074: errno=-5 IO failure
> Jan 23 18:42:39 my-machine kernel: BTRFS info (device sdb1): forced readonly
> ```

At the beginning, `btrfs check` gave the following output:

> ```
> $ sudo btrfsck /dev/sdb1
> Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb1
> UUID: a69162a3-aeb3-43c0-b74d-cfd280bfa8b6
> checking extents
> bad block 253655810048
> ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
> checking free space cache
> checking fs roots
> checking csums
> there are no extents for csum range 563128786944-564280360960
> csum exists for 563128786944-564280377344 but there is no extent record
> there are no extents for csum range 566428172288-567179472896
> Right section didn't have a record
> there are no extents for csum range 565354430464-567179472896
> Right section didn't have a record
> there are no extents for csum range 564280688640-567179472896
> Right section didn't have a record
> there are no extents for csum range 564280639488-567179472896
> csum exists for 564280639488-567179472896 but there is no extent record
> ERROR: errors found in csum tree
> found 1681395552256 bytes used, error(s) found
> total csum bytes: 0
> total tree bytes: 2406924288
> total fs tree bytes: 2279718912
> total extent tree bytes: 123813888
> btree space waste bytes: 350386565
> file data blocks allocated: 1685019078656
>  referenced 1685018304512
> ```

I ran `btrfs scrub`, but it interrupted itself sometimes (I had to re-mount the drive then):

> ```
> $ sudo btrfs scrub start -B /mnt/hd
> ERROR: scrubbing /mnt/hd failed for device id 1: ret=-1, errno=5 (Input/output error)
> scrub canceled for a69162a3-aeb3-43c0-b74d-cfd280bfa8b6
>   scrub started at Wed Jan 23 21:26:28 2019 and was aborted after 00:45:20
>   total bytes scrubbed: 509.99GiB with 0 errors
> ```

Using `btrfs scrub resume`, it did seem to finish, though:

> ```
> $ sudo btrfs scrub status /mnt/hd
> scrub status for a69162a3-aeb3-43c0-b74d-cfd280bfa8b6
>   scrub resumed at Wed Jan 23 22:24:05 2019 and finished after 01:52:15
>   total bytes scrubbed: 1.20TiB with 27163 errors
>   error details: csum=27163
>   corrected errors: 0, uncorrectable errors: 27163, unverified errors: 0
> ```

Before the ongoing run of `btrfs scrub`, I also tried `btrfs check --repair` once. That didn’t seem to change much, although subsequent runs of `btrfs check` showed “bad block 253432905728” instead of “bad block 253655810048”. Now, after the `btrfs scrub` has finished, `btrfs check` says

> ```
> Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb1
> UUID: a69162a3-aeb3-43c0-b74d-cfd280bfa8b6
> checking extents
> bad block 253432905728
> ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
> checking free space cache
> block group 253432430592 has wrong amount of free space, free space cache has 253722624 block group has 253689856
> ERROR: free space cache has more free space than block group item, this could leads to serious corruption, please contact btrfs developers
> failed to load free space cache for block group 253432430592
> ERROR: errors found in free space cache
> found 1681395535872 bytes used, error(s) found
> total csum bytes: 0
> total tree bytes: 2406203392
> total fs tree bytes: 2279718912
> total extent tree bytes: 123797504
> btree space waste bytes: 350047303
> file data blocks allocated: 1685019078656
>  referenced 1685018304512
> ```

This seems very worrisome! How did this happen? Did the filesystem just get really messed up somehow? Or is the drive failing (it’s not old and hasn’t been heavily used at all; SMART doesn’t seem to indicate anything problematic)?

Comment: I know some people have been issue free for years but btrfs is still getting but fixes every week so don't rely on it.

Comment: what version are you using `uname -r` ?

Comment: "_IO failure_", "_Input/output error_"...

Comment: To discover what happened, run a diagnostics on the drive; attempt to read every sector. It doesn't matter how young the drive is, nor the state SMART thinks the drive is in. If you're getting IO errors more likely than not you've got a failing drive, not a problem with BTRFS.

Comment: @user1133275 Sure, but this is really the most basic and light use of btrfs on a mostly empty drive. I’ve never heard of anyone running into trouble in this scenario for years (myself included). `uname -r`: 4.18.0-14-generic (this is Ubuntu 18.10).

Comment: No telling what is in an ubuntu kernel, might be worth trying 4.9.152 or 4.19.17 just look at the commit log if you think btrfs is stable.